# Entity Framework performance coding standards

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Do you have any suggestions for avoiding performance issues with EF6? I have seen articles about Find  vs Where and SingleOrDefault vs FirstOrDefault. 
Are there any coding standards to follow to avoid performance issues related to EF queries?
I am using EF6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve the performance of your queries if you consider the below mentioned options.

1. Caching in the Entity Framework
2. Autocompiled Queries
3. NoTracking Queries
4. Query Execution Options
5. Design time performance considerations
6. Loading Related Entities

You can refer this article to see more info : [**Performance Considerations for Entity Framework**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Comment: There are lot of changes in EF 6 and like to know the dos and don'ts.

Comment: Thanks Sampath for the link. I am specifically looking for EF6 changes. I read that lot of the performance issues are now taken care of in EF6.

Comment: OK Great.Hope you can accept the above solution then ? or if you have any spesific quetion ,feel free to ask it again.you can see how to do that here : http://stackoverflow.com/tour